# How to run Diesel migration with Rocket in production?

Tags: database, rust, database-migration, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I need to run Diesel database migrations in production for a Rocket-based app. Generally there are to ways to perform migrations for the database:

1. At application startup.
2. Separately from application startup.

I prefer the second option that would be invoked by using the `--migrate` flag for the application binary, but as the target application is fairly simple the first way will do just fine.

There is a [thread in the Diesel issue tracker](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/559) about running migrations in production and advise on how to do it:

> 1. Add `diesel_migrations` to your dependencies
> 2. Include an `extern crate diesel_migrations` in your crate, and make sure to decorate it with `#[macro_use]`
> 3. At the beginning of your code, add `embed_migrations!()`
> 4. To run the migrations, Use `embedded_migrations::run(&db_conn)`

In `main.rs` I made:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel_migrations;

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket_contrib;

#[database("my_db_name")]
pub struct DbConn(diesel::PgConnection);

fn main() {
    // Update database
    embed_migrations!();
    embedded_migrations::run(&DbConn);
    // Launch the app
    ...
}
```

This leads to the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(diesel::r2d2::PooledConnection<<diesel::PgConnection as rocket_contrib::databases::Poolable>::Manager>) -> DbConn {DbConn}: diesel::Connection` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:30:30
   |
29 |     embed_migrations!();
   |     --------------------
   |     |
   |     required by this bound in `main::embedded_migrations::run`
30 |     embedded_migrations::run(&DbConn);
   |                              ^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Connection` is not implemented for `fn(diesel::r2d2::PooledConnection<<diesel::PgConnection as rocket_contrib::databases::Poolable>::Manager>) -> DbConn {DbConn}`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel_migrations::MigrationConnection` for `fn(diesel::r2d2::PooledConnection<<diesel::PgConnection as rocket_contrib::databases::Poolable>::Manager>) -> DbConn {DbConn}`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `run` with a connection instance and not the connection type? Ie: `let db_conn = whatever; embedded_migrations::run (&db_conn);`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you dug in the diesel issue tracker for that incomplete information instead using the [corresponding](https://docs.rs/diesel_migrations/1.4.0/diesel_migrations/macro.embed_migrations.html) documentation.
Beside of that you will need a instance of something that implements `Connection` so either do whatever to rocket documentation (as I see their magic macro stuff there) suggests or just establish a new `PgConnection` on application start to run the migrations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Googled some more and found working example [here](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/master/examples/todo/src/main.rs).

Key code

```
use rocket::Rocket;
use rocket::fairing::AdHoc;

// This macro from `diesel_migrations` defines an `embedded_migrations` module
// containing a function named `run`. This allows the example to be run and
// tested without any outside setup of the database.
embed_migrations!();

#[database("sqlite_database")]
pub struct DbConn(SqliteConnection);

fn run_db_migrations(rocket: Rocket) -> Result<Rocket, Rocket> {
    let conn = DbConn::get_one(&rocket).expect("database connection");
    match embedded_migrations::run(&*conn) {
        Ok(()) => Ok(rocket),
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to run database migrations: {:?}", e);
            Err(rocket)
        }
    }
}

fn rocket() -> Rocket {
    rocket::ignite()
        .attach(DbConn::fairing())
        .attach(AdHoc::on_attach("Database Migrations", run_db_migrations))
        .mount("/", StaticFiles::from("static/"))
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .mount("/todo", routes![new, toggle, delete])
        .attach(Template::fairing())
}
```

Comment: Note that this has changed since release 2.0.0 — https://github.com/Diesel-rs/Diesel/blob/master/guide_drafts/migration_guide.md#diesel_migration-rewrite

Answer (score 5):

Building off of SS_Rebelious' answer, here's what I had to do for Rocket 0.5

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel_migrations;

use capt_server::api::routes;
use diesel_migrations::embed_migrations;
use envy;
use rocket::fairing::AdHoc;
use rocket::{Build, Rocket};
use rocket_sync_db_pools::database;

#[database("sqlite_db")]
pub struct Db(diesel::SqliteConnection);

// This macro from `diesel_migrations` defines an `embedded_migrations` module
// containing a function named `run`. This allows the example to be run and
// tested without any outside setup of the database.
embed_migrations!();

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .attach(Db::fairing())
        .attach(AdHoc::try_on_ignite("Database Migrations", migrate))
        .mount("/", routes())
}

async fn migrate(rocket: Rocket<Build>) -> Result<Rocket<Build>, Rocket<Build>> {
    let db = Db::get_one(&rocket).await.expect("database connection");
    db.run(|conn| match embedded_migrations::run(&*conn) {
        Ok(()) => Ok(rocket),
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to run database migrations: {:?}", e);
            Err(rocket)
        }
    })
    .await
}
```

Comment: After many days trying to get this to work, your solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks!